# In javascript Form submission not taken e.preventDefault() function

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

when Submit button is clicked i want to validate the form and in ajax call want to check captcha is correct or not.If it is not correct then want a error message and prevent form submission.

Here is my javascript code

```
$(document).on("click","#submit-reservation",function(e){
    if($('#myform').isValid()){

      var cval = $('#captcha-input').val();
      var dataString = 'captachacheck=true&cval='+cval;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{/literal}{$smarty.session.siteloc}reservation/checkcaptcha/{literal}",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data.status);
          if(data.status == "error"){
            $("#captcha-wrap").append('<span class="help-block form-error" style="color: red;"> * Invalid Captcha</span>');
             e.preventDefault();
          }
          else{
           $('#submit-reservation').click();
          }


        }
      });

    }


  });
```

Comment: You can preventDefault, then use `.submit()` after form you have validated the form

Answer (score 0):

I guess in your form , you have submit button declared as :-

```
<input type="submit" id="submit-reservation">
```

Even though you have added event handler , the ajax call is asynchronous and as a result e.preventDefault wont work because the form would be submitted till then.

Use

```
<button id="submit-reservation">Submit</button>
<input type="submit" id="submitForm" hidden>
```

And in ajax call :-

```
      if(data.status == "error"){
        $("#captcha-wrap").append('<span class="help-block form-error" style="color: red;"> * Invalid Captcha</span>');

      }
      else{
       $('#submitForm').trigger("click");
      }
```

Here you are trigger the event when there is no error returned from your call

Comment: try using $('#submitForm').click()

Answer (score 0):

Use submit to trigger submit,place the prevent function outside the ajax

```
$(document).on("click","#submit-reservation",function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if($('#myform').isValid()){

      var cval = $('#captcha-input').val();
      var dataString = 'captachacheck=true&cval='+cval;
      $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{/literal}{$smarty.session.siteloc}reservation/checkcaptcha/{literal}",
        data: dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {
          console.log(data.status);
          if(data.status == "error"){
            $("#captcha-wrap").append('<span class="help-block form-error" style="color: red;"> * Invalid Captcha</span>');

          }
          else{
           $('#submit-reservation').closest('form').submit();
          }


        }
      });

    }


  });
```

Comment: If I put e.preventDefault() function outside the ajax ,the form submission not placed .

Comment: what do you mean by `the form submission not placed `?

Comment: I cant Submit the form.

Comment: this is the desired behaviour, if the ajax is successful and you don't have a status = "error" then the form should submit